# Spring Batch - Retrieve the row number of file i am reading

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-batch

I am reading a TSV file using flatfileitemreader, While processing the records, i want to store row number of the record i am reading from my tsv file. I have a taskExecutor(for multiple threads) which makes it impossible for me to correctly get the row number of the record i am reading

Answer (score 0):

> I have a taskExecutor(for multiple threads) which makes it impossible for me to correctly get the row number of the record i am reading

Multi-threading is not compatible with what you are looking for. Concurrent threads will read items in an undefined order, that's why you are getting incorrect row numbers. You need to single threaded-step for this to work.

Comment: But for faster processing i need the multi threaded implementation. can u pls suggest any alternative in that case